# What pieces are used to create this Djembe MOC?

Tags: part-identification

I sent an E-mail to the creator but haven't heard back. Any thoughts on the part numbers on [the Lego djembe](http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/240648)? Trying to build one for Christmas gift :-)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, the base is made out of a 4x4 red plate (#3031) and a 1x4 red plate (#3710).
On top, you have 3 1x4 red tiles (#2431) arranged in a U shape within the center of the U 3 1x2 tiles with center stud (red - #3794) and 1 regular 1x2 tile (#3069), like so:

```
________
|_______|
| |_o_| |
| |___| |
| |.|.| |
|_|_|_|_|
```

The seat is a hinge piece (#3938 on #3937), sitting on 2 of the 1x2 tiles with center stud, whereas the djembe itself is a 1x1 cone (#4589b), an inverted 2x2 round disc (radar - #4740), a 2x2 round disc with X hole in center (#4032) and then the finishing 2x2 round tile (with optional pattern - variants of #4150).

The cone, inverted disc and 2x2 round pieces are attached together using a Lego Friends magic wand [#87994pb01](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87994pb01) or a Bar 3L ([#87994](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87994)), though I don't have access to such a bar and hence wasn't able to try it out in my draft build, but I did test out a Bar 4L (#30374) and know that that works if trimmed down to about 3L. Alternatively you can use a tool screwdriver (#6246a), but this doesn't secure the top 2 round pieces very well.

Here are step-by-step instructions :) :
[image: step 1][image: step 2][image: step 3][image: step 4][image: step 5][image: step 6][image: step 7]

Comment: I'm guessing a small rod (Bar 3L) or similar? Possibly trimmed/halved.

Comment: The only small rods I have are 4L, and even they don't fit tightly onto the 2x2 round plate. In my quick build the top stays on relatively ok, but it is not a normal strong Lego fit and the top of the djembe will fall off if you hold the model under an angle.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: You are probably right - the Bar 4L (#30374) fits into the X of the 2x2 round plate. As there is no "Bar 3L" in the Lego catalog (according to BrickLink) it is likely a 4L bar trimmed down to the right length. I have updated my answer with this info.

Comment: I would use a [#6246a small screwdriver](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6246a) to hold the top to the base of the drum.

Comment: @PGmath that's what I originally suggested in my post, see `the best I have figured out so far is to stick a tool screwdriver (#6246a) inside, but this doesn't secure the top 2 round pieces very well.`

Comment: I found the right bar! It is a Friends magic wand [#87994pb01](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87994pb01). Updating this in my answer.

Comment: @PhilB.: Actually, there is a generic Bar 3L too: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87994

Comment: The 3L was used in the Dwarf Warrior minifigure as I recall - his axe handle was shorter than the classic light saber/Harry Potter wand.

Comment: Thank You!!! I have ordered and will post pic. Once again Thank You :-)

Comment: I just tried this build with a 3L bar and it doesn't fit. The bar sticks out the bottom enough that you can't put the cone onto a stud, not even a hollow stud like the one on your jumper.

Comment: The screwdriver works fairly well if you push it up until it secures the dish to the round plate, and then only a little bit of the handle pokes downward but it's enough to attach the dish to the cone.

Comment: The screwdriver trick works so-so, it doesn't really secure the dish to the round plate very well (at least not on my try-out build). As suspected by Zhaph - Ben Duguid and myself, there might need to be a little trimming done on the 3L Bar :(. Thanks for trying it out @Mr. Shiny and New :)